# OO design issue

Tags: c#, object

I have a class which represents a step in a registration process. I have certain things that I want the step to perform when a user clicks save after filling out the step and then other things that I want the step to do when we are at the end of the registration process and save is invoked on the step at that stage. I have decided to use the idea of having a state but it seems to have a bad code smell about it. Any comments on how to improve this design?

```
public class Step1
{
    public Enum State
    {
        InProcess = 1,
        EndProcess
    }

    private State processState;

    public Step1(State currentState)
    {
        processState = currentState;
    }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        bool result; 

        if(processState = State.InProcess)
        {
            result = PerformCheck1();
        }
        else if(processState = State.EndProcess)
        {
            result = PerformCheck2();
            result = PerformCheck3();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot determine process state");
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void Save()
    {   
        if(processState = State.InProcess)
        {
            DoThing1();
        }
        else if(processState = State.EndProcess)
        {
            DoThing2();
            DoThing3();
            DoThing4();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot determine process state");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding other issues with the code, if you go with this design you are going to wind up with a single monolithic class for Step. I would create a IStep interface and make each step its own class:

```
public interface IStep
{
    bool IsValid { get; }
    void Save();
}

public class BeginStep : IStep
{
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return PerformCheck1();
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        DoThing1();
    }
}

public class EndStep : IStep
{
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            // Skipped PerformCheck2() since the result is directly overwritten
            return PerformCheck3();
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        DoThing2();
        DoThing3();
        DoThing4();
    }
}
```

Comment: Each step was going to be it's own class. The sample class is called Step1, it's that when you save a step in process there are certain save actions vs when we are at Step5 (final step) it then calls save on all the previous steps but wants a different set of actions completed as we are in an endstate process.

Answer (score 0):

If I undersdand your answer (+ your comment on Justin's answer) correctly, each step can be in a "processing" and a "completed" state and depending on which state it is in, you want to call different `Save()` and `IsValid()` methods.

Furthermore, every step is automatically "completed" once you reach the final step.

From the code you posted, it doesn't seem as if a step needs to know in which state he currently is. You just want to perform different actions depending on whether or not you are on the final page.

Is there a reason why you don't want to create specific methods that encapsulate the "completed" logic (e.g. `SaveCompleted()` and `IsValidCompleted()`)?

I don't see why the Step class should decide which code to execute, since the decision is made outside the step, where you keep track of the active step.

"Magic methods" that automatically do the right thing based on some hidden state that can be modified from outside often lead to inconsistency, unexpected problems and long debugging sessions.

I would advise you to create an interface as Justin suggested, with 2 additional methods that contain the "completed" code. (There are many ways to achieve the same, like using an abstract base class instead (with the possible advantage that the "completed" methods can default to the "processing" methods) or a separate interface (to only expose the "completed" methods to the final page, without enabling it to call the regualr methods) etc. etc.)

Comment: I suppose I just thought it looked tidier to have the method look after the logic flow rather than separating out into individual methods. I take your point though re:separation of concerns. I'll have a look at the suggestions at the end of your post also

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Justin’s answer, here is a Wikipedia link to [Finite-state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine), as what you are trying to create is a Finite-state machine. The link gives theoretical background knowledge on the theme. If your registration process becomes more complicated, a State/Event table as mentioned in the article will help to formulate the flow of events.